# Intermittent "index = -1" when getting rows from DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview

When doing this:

```
        foreach (DataGridView currentGridView in tabControl.SelectedTab.Controls.OfType<DataGridView>())
        {

            rows = new DataGridViewRow[currentGridView.RowCount];        
            currentGridView.Rows.CopyTo(rows, 0);
            page = 0;

            printDocDetail.DocumentName = "Contact List Detailed";
            printDocDetail.Print();

        }
```

I often get this result:

[image: result]

And that depends on the run. For the same DataGridView data, one run will return the data correctly, the next will return all index=-1 except for the first one.

What is causing this?

P.S. Using DataGridViewRowCollection or a simple array results to the same thing.

Comment: Does this line `rows = new DataGridViewRow[currentGridView.RowCount];` work? There's no constructor that's takes an int and square brackets?

Comment: That line creates an array of DataGridViewRow with all null elements

Comment: It does work `currentGridView.RowCount` returns the reight amount of rows thus creating the array correctly.
The array is declared at class level `DataGridViewRow[] rows`
It's after the `currentGridView.Rows.CopyTo(rows, 0);` line that the issue happens. And it's intermittent.

Comment: @Steve yes, it's normal before I fill it with the content on the next line.

Comment: Yes I know that. But could you tell us when that dump of the debugger has been made?

Comment: @Steve sure! just after `currentGridView.Rows.CopyTo(rows, 0);` It does persist further, such as in the PrintEven handler.

Comment: Can you explain why you need to make a CopyTo? It doesn't create a new set of DataGridViewRows, it just make a copy of the reference still pointing at the same rows. Could you try with: _DataGridViewRow[] rows = currentGridView.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().ToArray();_

Comment: Awesome! I was suspecting the data was the root of the trouble but wasn't copying it correctly. Your solution worked fine :)

Comment: It means the rows are [shared.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow?view=windowsdesktop-7.0#remarks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was to use unbinded data by copying the data to a new array rather then copying the pointers to the data:

```
rows = currentGridView.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().ToArray();
```

Instead of

```
rows = new DataGridViewRow[currentGridView.RowCount];
currentGridView.Rows.CopyTo(rows, 0);
```

Answer (score -1):

Go to TableAdapter. Next click on little arrow to edit query. Click on ID and under ID properties change AutoIncrementSeed from -1 change to 1 and AutoIncrementStep from -1 to 1. Will fix the problem

TableAdapter:
[image: TableAdapter]

ID:
[image: ID]

ID Properties:
[image: ID Properties]

Form:
[image: Form]